# How to compile with cutil?

Tags: c++

I am using a code from someone else. When compiling it I got the following error: " référence indéfinie vers « CUtil::CUtil() ".
I guess I am missing a package or library? Or is it a problem with my compiler? (gcc version 5.4.0).
I am on ubuntu.
Any idea how I should procees to be able to compile?

Edit: it is a linkage issue. I have all the files I need in mu directory and here is the script to compile:

```
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC GeoConvert.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC GlobalFunctions.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC Util.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC TbwInput.cpp
g++ -shared -o libTbwInput.so GeoConvert.o GlobalFunctions.o Util.o TbwInput.o

g++ -c -Wall -fPIC Atmosphere.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC GlobalFunctions.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC Interface.cpp
g++ -c -Wall -fPIC WriteInputFile.cpp

g++ -shared -o libInterface.so Atmosphere.o GlobalFunctions.o Interface.o WriteInputFile.o

g++ -c -Wall -fPIC CalllTBWinterface.cpp
#g++ -c -Wall -fPIC stdafx.cpp

g++ -shared -o libTBWinterfaceWrapper.so CalllTBWinterface.o #stdafx.o
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'/home/bomble/TIARE/HasanKhan/MDO_GITHUB/All Libraries/1.TBWinterfaceWrapper/'

g++ -o TBWinterfaceWrapper TBWinterfaceWrapper.cpp -L'/home/bomble/TIARE/HasanKhan/MDO_GITHUB/All Libraries/1.TBWinterfaceWrapper' -lTbwInput -lInterface -lTBWinterfaceWrapper
```

All but the last step go fine. And then I have error about things not find even if they are in the cpp compiled at the beginning....

Comment: Is cutil only pour GPU code?

Comment: Not a problem with your compiler, you are missing a package or library. I am not that good in french, so I can't say if you have forgotten to include a header file, or forgotten to link with the right library. When you get a library from someone else, it is typically a good idea to consult that "somebody else" on how to use it.

Comment: It looks like you have included the header for `CUtil`, which gives the *declaration*, but did not link the *definition*, which usually lives either in a `.cpp` file or, if in built form, in a `.a` or `.so`. You need to add that definition to your build commands.

Comment: Oh, forgot to say, there *could* be a problem with your compiler if the library has been compiled with a compiler that has a different ABI than yours. In that case, you have to recompile the library with your compiler.

Comment: "référence indéfinie" means unresolved reference in french.

Comment: @HAL9000  indeed it is a linkage problem. but I still can't figure it out, see the question for more details

Comment: Order of libraries matters when linking. If `libA.so` depends on `libB.so` then `-lB` must come before `-lA` when linking